# When I add tasks to my to do list they double

Tags: flutter, dart

When I add task in the `TextField` in `AppBar` its double with the task which was there earlier.
Its like created container with all of saved tasks.
What can I do to make them show up separately? without doubling?

The picture shows what the problem is.

[image: The problem]

Here is fragment of my code:

```dart
class ToDoListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToDoListPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.onSave,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function onSave;

  @override
  State<ToDoListPage> createState() => _ToDoListPageState();
}

class _ToDoListPageState extends State<ToDoListPage> {
  String? taskName;
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  IconData buttonIcon = Icons.add;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => ToDoListCubit(ToDoRepository())..start2(),
        child: BlocBuilder<ToDoListCubit, ToDoListState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.errorMessage.isNotEmpty) {
            return Center(
                child: Text('Something went wrong ${state.errorMessage}'));
          }
          if (state.isLoading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade50,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10, top: 8.6),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Add Task',
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.brown),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.brown),
                          ),
                        ),
                        controller: textController,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              taskName = newValue;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 7.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.brown.shade300,
                            onPrimary: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //context.read<ToDoListCubit>().addtask(taskName!);
                            context.read<ToDoListCubit>().addtask(taskName!);
                            textController.clear();
                          },
                          child: Icon(buttonIcon)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: const BodyToDoList(),
          );
        }));
  }
}

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TaskList({
    Key? key,
    required this.taskList,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<ToDoModels> taskList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: taskList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var task = taskList[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(task.title),
            trailing: Checkbox(
              value: task.isDone,
              onChanged: ((value) {}),
            ),
          );
        },
```

Here is cubit:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:nataliaaplikacja/app/home/to_do_list_page/model/todo_models.dart';
import 'package:nataliaaplikacja/repositories/todo_repository.dart';

part 'to_do_list_state.dart';

class ToDoListCubit extends Cubit<ToDoListState> {
  ToDoListCubit(
    this._todoRepository,
  ) : super(ToDoListState(
          allTasks: [],
          errorMessage: '',
          isLoading: false,
        ));

  final ToDoRepository _todoRepository;

  StreamSubscription? _streamSubscription;

  Future<void> addtask(String taskName) async {
    try {
      await _todoRepository.addtask(taskName);
      emit(ToDoListState(
        saved: true,
        errorMessage: '',
        isLoading: false,
      ));
    } catch (error) {
      emit(ToDoListState(
        errorMessage: error.toString(),
        isLoading: false,
      ));
    }
  }

  Future<void> start2() async {
    emit(
      ToDoListState(
        errorMessage: '',
        isLoading: true,
        allTasks: [],
      ),
    );

    _streamSubscription = _todoRepository.getTaskItemStream().listen((data) {
      final todoModels = data;

      emit(
        ToDoListState(
          allTasks: todoModels,
          isLoading: false,
          errorMessage: '',
        ),
      );
    })
      ..onError((error) {
        emit(
          ToDoListState(
            isLoading: false,
            errorMessage: error.toString(),
          ),
        );
      });
  }

  Future<void> removetask({required String documentID}) async {
    try {
      await _todoRepository.deletetask(id: documentID);
    } catch (error) {
      emit(
        ToDoListState(
          errorMessage: error.toString(),
          isLoading: false,
        ),
      );
      start2();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _streamSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

`ToDoRepository`:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:nataliaaplikacja/app/home/to_do_list_page/model/todo_models.dart';

class ToDoRepository {
  Stream<List<ToDoModels>> getTaskItemStream() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('task')
        .snapshots()
        .map((querySnapshot) {
      return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        return ToDoModels(title: doc['name'], id: doc.id,
          
        );
      }).toList();
    });
  }


  Future<void> deletetask({required String id}) {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('task').doc(id).delete();
  }

  Future<void> addtask(String taskname) async {
    {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('task').add(
        {
          'name' : taskname,
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```